# Allure - generate allure-results with jar

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, allure

I have a big java .jar with dependencies and classes, when excute the .jar, I need to generate the folder "allure-results", Is it possible to do that?

1) execute the -jar
2) run the tests
3) generate the folder allure-results

the idea is to run without maven.

----- Solved

i create a main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       JUnitCore engine = new JUnitCore();
       engine.addListener(new AllureJunit4());
       engine.run(testsSuitName.class);

 }
```

when you exec the fat jar and the test its ok, the jar create the folder "allure-results"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `AllureJunit4` listener to `JUnitCore`:

```
JUnitCore engine = new JUnitCore();
engine.addListener(new AllureJunit4());
engine.run(testsSuitName.class);
```

Then you need to specify AspectJ Weaver javaagent when run your fat jar:

```
$ java -jar --javaagent:"/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar" tests.jar
```

In order to configure results folder you can use `allure.results.directory` system property