# How to generate allure report after running selenium test jar in docker environment

Tags: docker, selenium, junit4, allure

I'm trying to execute an allure report after running a selenium executable jar in a docker container. I've been trying to get this working for 4 days, can someone advise if I'm missing something or using the wrong approach?

What I've done and tried so far:

- Built the selenium test executable jar (fatjar) using a dockerfile.
- Installed allure using the dockerfile while building the test jar file.
- Added AllureJunit4 after reading this [Allure - generate allure-results with jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560256/allure-generate-allure-results-with-jar) which generates the correct directory when running in local but doesn't generate the directory in docker.
- Inspected image and running container using `docker exec -it` to look for `allure-results` dir.
- Used `docker cp` to try and copy out folders that I think might have allure reports.
- The Entrypoint in my docker file is `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "automation-tests.jar"]`. So when I do `docker build --tag <tagname> .` and `docker run <tagname>` the jar file runs and executes with no errors.

Below is a sample of my dockerfile

```
RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.106/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip 
RUN mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver 
RUN chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver 
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver

RUN wget https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/releases/download/allure-core-1.4.24.RC2/allure-commandline.zip && \
     unzip allure-commandline.zip && bin/allure && rm allure-commandline.zip

FROM gradle:6.1.1-jdk8 AS sdk
WORKDIR /auto

WORKDIR /auto/build 
RUN gradle clean fatJar -x test

FROM runtime AS final 
COPY --from=sdk path/to/jar/automation-stuff*.jar ./auto-testing.jar 

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "auto-testing.jar"]
```

None of these have produced any results so if anyone can help me then I'd truly appreciate it.
So just to clarify this is only a problem generating the allure report.

Comment: can you provide more info, errors, code or similar? How you start the tests, are the tests executing or is it just a problem with the reporting?

Comment: did you "obfuscate" `path/to/jar/automation-stuff*.jar`? or is it an error? it wouldn't make sense to obfuscate it since it's inside the docker image. What errors do you receive? btw, I see no building command for auto-testing.jar

Comment: yes i obfuscated that and also removed some of the proprietary info from the dockerfile. There are no errors, the test/jar run just fine I just cannot produce the allure report

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Allure Docker Service container. Once your tests generate the allure results you can send them using the Allure API and see your updated report.
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service#send-results-through-api

Comment: This solution works perfectly for the above. allure-docker-server is a great tool.